# refresh angular component after delete item

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to refresh my page of contact list after delete one contact in the table, but it doesn't work, any idea ?
This is the list of contact in contact.component.ts file

```
 Swal.fire({
    title: 'Voulez-vous supprimer ce contact?',
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Supprimer!',
    cancelButtonText: 'Annuler'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
       return this.contactsService.deleteContact(id).subscribe(data => {
        Swal.fire(
          'Effectué!',
          'Le contact a été supprimé.',
          'success'
        )
       location.reload();
  },error => {
    console.log("Erreur lors de la suppression du contact : ",error);
  });
    } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
      Swal.fire(
        'Cancelled',
        'Your imaginary file is safe :)',
        'error'
      )
    }
  })
}
```

I use location.reload but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you really need the whole page or maybe just refresh the list to reflect the deleted item?

Comment: try to update data source after the deleting it. then it will be automatically rendering changes

Answer (score 0):

You shoud try

```
Swal.fire('Effectué!','Le contact a été supprimé.','success').then(() => location.reload())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Import these 
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';    
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

// Add constructor (If not already added)
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document){ }

// Add the following line where you want to reload the page
this.document.location.reload();
```